How can I do full disk encryption on external drive after install?
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 and have an external ext4 drive with 11TB of files/data mounted on /mydrive.
I don't care about encryption of /home or /swap.
I see lots of posts about encrypting on /home and /swap on install, but I don't see anything about encrypting an external drive. I want to encrypt the volume like "FileVault" would do under Mac OS.
If it's possible how do I do that?

You have to backup/copy the data somewhere else. Then encrypt the drive. Then copy your data into the encrypted partition.
